# convert datetime to R (i.e May 18th)

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

```
df$date <- 'May 18th 2020, 16:19:54.102'
```

This is a factor. What is the format for `as.POSIXct(...)` to get this as an actual date time?

End result should be `05-18-2020 16:19:54` as a `POSIXct`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mdy_hms` to convert to `Datetime` class and then with `format` change the format

```
library(lubridate)
format(mdy_hms(df$date), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "05-18-2020 16:19:54"
```

---

Or in `base R` with `as.POSIXlt`

```
format(as.POSIXlt(df$date, format = '%b %dth %Y, %T'), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "05-18-2020 16:19:54"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(date =  'May 18th 2020, 16:19:54.102')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `as.POSIXct` from base R :

```
as.POSIXct('May 18th 2020, 16:19:54.102', format = '%b %dth %Y, %T', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2020-05-18 16:19:54 UTC"
```

We can also use `strptime` but it returns `POSIXlt` class.

```
strptime('May 18th 2020, 16:19:54.102', format = '%b %dth %Y, %T', tz = 'UTC')
```

Note that using `%b` is locale-specific.